# How to tell if a C++ exe has been explicitly called by another program

Tags: python, c++, exe

I've written a program in C++14 that gets compiled into an exe. It can be run normally by the user double clicking on it, or it can be called by a Python 3 program in the same file directory (using subprocess.Popen). The behavior of the C++ program depends on which way it was called, and I was wondering if there's an easy way to tell (in the C++ program) at runtime.

One method I've thought of is having the Python program write something to a textfile, which would let the C++ program know how it was called. But I'm looking for a better way, if one exists.

Comment: Perhaps consider command line parameters, or checking if the python program is running? Is OS a concern here or does it need to be OS independent?

Comment: You'll be surprised to learn that every program is "called by another program". When you double click on a program, how do you think it gets started? That doesn't happen spontaneously, by itself, the program which manages your desktop calls your program to execute.

Comment: A command-line parameter is the cleanest way to accomplish this.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I wouldn't be surprised because I already know. The title has been edited.

Comment: @Tas Thanks, I'll look into that. Right now the OS shouldn't be a concern for the application.

Comment: Bear in mind that users can also call your program with a command line parameter, so it's not bullet-proof, but might suffice for your needs

Comment: I forget how to read parent process information in C++, but I'm pretty sure python can do that by `psutil` module, and this module has core C implement. So I guess you could try to get process tree by some C++ libraries, such as `boost`? I'm not sure. But as @Tas said, I don't think you're program need to care about if it was started by `explorer.exe`

Comment: @Tas A user can also write a Python program and run this executable from there. No approach will be bulletproof.